# Forest: What is causing the misalignment?

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
forked edges,
[S[subject [pronoun [I]]] [predicate [verb [saw]]] [object [noun [Jane.]]]]
\end{forest}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

like this?

[image]

for align of nodes in tree, as you like to have, you should tell this to `forest`. see mwe below:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
forked edges,
[S
    [subject
        [pronoun [I]]
    ]
    [predicate,before computing xy={s/.average={s}{siblings}}% <---
        [verb [saw]]
    ] [object
        [noun
            [Jane.]
        ]
    ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it just me or does the top node (right below the S) look thicker than the rest?

Comment: @Mast, it can looks darker due to pdf viewer artifact. if you zoom image (magnify it) than you will see, that all lines are the same. the same is valid for nodes' texts.